# Scheme Function to remove one list's items from another

Tags: list, function, null, scheme

I'm trying to create a scheme function which given two lists L1 and L2, will remove any items present in L2 from L1.

I have a small start, but I don't know exactly what else to do.

```
(define (remove L1 L2)
(((null? L2) L1))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a code snippet for the simple case.

```
(define (remove L1 L2)
  (cond ((null? L1) '())
        ((memv (car L1) L2) (remove (cdr L1) L2))
        (else  (cons (car L1) (remove (cdr L1) L2)))))
```

Remember that in Scheme, or any functional language, the question you need to ask is not *"what should I be doing?"*, but rather you should ask *"what value do I need to produce?"*.

Please note that this simple example doesn't handle nested lists.  So `(remove '(A (C D)) '(B C D))` would produce `(A (C D))`.  Handling nesting lists is left as an exercise for the reader :D

Comment: First, you can use `memv` instead of your `isin?` function. Second, Scheme style is not like C: never put close parens on a separate line; always put them on the last line with actual text.

Comment: @ryanc: +1 Agree on both counts. I felt the need to correct the formatting on the spot, but I left the `isin?` in place.

Comment: Also, instead of nested `if`s, use `cond` instead: it's much tidier.

Comment: @rynac @Chris Jester-Young Thanks for reminding me about memv and cond.  It's been a while since I dealt with scheme.  As for the close parens, the reason I place close parens on a seperate line is because it makes matching parens so much easier and I find it much more readable.  However, I realize this is just a personal preference and I really don't care enough about it to push the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use [SRFI 1](http://srfi.schemers.org/srfi-1/srfi-1.html)'s `lset-difference`:

```
(lset-difference = '(1 2 3 4 5) '(3 4 5 5 6))
; => (1 2)
```

The `=`, in my example, is the comparison function. If your lists contain strings, say, instead of numbers, then you should use `string=?` in place of `=`.